# filtering records based on n:m table criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, where-clause

I have table `product`

```
 ID int 
 name nvarchar()

 dummy data: (1,'car'), (2,'bike')
```

I have table `parameters`

```
 ID int
 name nvarchar()

 dummy data: (1,'abs'), (2,'audio'), (3,'eps'), (4,'air conditioning')
```

and finally I have n:m table `product_parameters` which holds information about parameters for product.

```
 ID int
 id_product int
 id_parameter int

 dummy data: 

 (id,product,parameter)
 (1, 1, 1), 
 (2, 1, 2), 
 (3, 1, 3),
 (4, 2, 1)
```

How do I create select which:

1. shows everything is parameters is not defined in search
2. shows car and bike because they both have parameter abs
3. shows only car because it searches for abs, eps, audi

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I created only 3 parameters but think of it like unlimited number, whether 10, 20 or 30 or more ... basically is there a way how to build select in such a way that it will query one parameter if needed or 20 parameters if needed.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
SELECT * FROM product PR
JOIN product_parameters PP ON PR.ID=PP.id_product
JOIN parameters PA ON PP.id_parameter=PA.ID
```

Second:

```
SELECT PR.* FROM product PR
JOIN product_parameters PP ON PR.ID=PP.id_product
JOIN parameters PA ON PP.id_parameter=PA.ID
WHERE PA.name = 'abs'
```

Third:

```
SELECT PR.* FROM product PR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_parameters PP JOIN parameters PA ON PP.id_parameter=PA.ID WHERE PP.id_product=PR.ID AND PA.name='abs')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_parameters PP JOIN parameters PA ON PP.id_parameter=PA.ID WHERE PP.id_product=PR.ID AND PA.name='eps')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_parameters PP JOIN parameters PA ON PP.id_parameter=PA.ID WHERE PP.id_product=PR.ID AND PA.name='audi')
```

Comment: What if I have 30 parameters? do I need to repeat where exists 30x times ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.. since you're requesting that the row must be attached to all parameters.  If you're saying "any of" the parameters, it's much smaller.  If you have that many parameters, I'd suggest taking the product_parameters join out of the subqueries and doing it in the main query as well.  You can have your program programatically generate the long list of EXISTS statements.